# Python: pyodbc can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server-2008-r2, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 using `pyodbc`.

This is my code snippet:

```
conn_strng = ['Driver={SQL Server Native Client 
11},'Database=db_name','uid=user','pwd=password','trusted_source=yes']
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(';'.join(conn_strng))
```

I get the following error:

> ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source name not found or no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I have installed the SQL Server ODBC Driver 11. I am using Windows Sever 2012. I have searched in Stackoverflow and tried by changing the Driver string and other string formatting (i.e. no space etc.) but no luck.

Do I need to specify `port` as well?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I have found out a solution. Below is the correct connection string

```
Driver={SQL Server} #<--Note that it is different than earlier
Database=db_name
uid=user
pwd=password
trusted_source=no #<--if we set this 'yes' then it will try to connect the DB with windows login. This was causing error
```

I think it is better to use `Driver={SQL Server}` for a safer side.